# Separating a desktop application into a client-server application

Tags: c#, .net, sql, client-server

I have a multi-tiered desktop application with a well separated modular design. So far it has been working on a single PC, but now the scope was revised to create a distributed system with a server and multiple clients on a local network.

The Client requests historical data as well as real-time data updates by subscribing to various channels.

The Server read the historical data from the database and real-time data from the PLC and sends it to a client. If a client performs any data modifications, the server must notify all the connected clients of any changes.

I have looked into WCF as well as this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPServClntCommRMIFrmwrk.aspx

Does anybody have any other recommendations on how to approach this task?

Comment: Wow, that's a nice article on codeproject :)

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a typical [Client-Server Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) with P[ublish-Subscribe Paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe). Look at the articles to get more insight to how similar architectural problems are approached.